# How do I pop up the keyboard in Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm trying to duplicate the following behavior (WM6).

Go to Settings -> About -> Device ID. The Device Name textbox gets the focus, causing the onscreen keyboard to pop up.

I'd like to be able to do the same in my application, preferably in managed code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The onscreen keyboard is in the Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms namespace.

Add a project reference to that and you'll have the InputPanel control available, add one of those to your form then in your code behind.

```
private void txtField_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Enabled == show
     inputPanel.Enabled = true;
}

private void txtField_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     inputPanel.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Who could imagine the keyboard was called InputPanel? :)

Comment: I have a form in which they are n number of Textboxes, how will enable inputpanel for all Textboxes?

Comment: @NKhan You can assign the same txtField_GotFocus and txtField_LostFocus events to all of the n Textboxes. You can then just cast the sender to a TextBox to figure out which one it is.

Comment: @TristanWarner-Smith thanx for your prompt response, can you show me the code how to achieve this.

Comment: ALso this method is enabling small keyboard how can get large keyboard??

Comment: @NKhan If you create them programatically it would be: yourTextFieldControlName1.GotFocus += this.txtField_GotFocus then yourTextFieldControlName2.GotFocus += this.txtField_GotFocus. If you do it in the designer instead it's on the events tab.

Comment: @NKhan No idea about different sizes, as far as I know it gives you the standard one. Just put a breakpoint and explore the options on inputPanel. This post is from 5 years ago, I haven't done Windows Mobile dev since 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I would add that you also need to instantiate an instance of the Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.InputPanel class for your project (in addtion to adding a reference to the namespace as noted by [TreeUK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29553/treeuk)).

The easiest way to do this is to drag an InputPanel control onto your Windows Form in Design mode. Whatever you name your InputPanel instance would be what you reference in the event handlers for your form fields.